# Query for associations N-N

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

I have tables on my DB as follow:

[image]

NB:
ID_A foreign key references A(ID)
ID_B foreign key references B(ID)

Now my problem is this:
Suppose one list of A ids like these {12,15,26}, I want to find all the values of B for which are associated all the values into the set.
I can do something like this:

```
select ID_B from AB where ID_A = 12
intersect
select ID_B from AB where ID_A = 15
intersect
select ID_B from AB where ID_A = 26
```

But it is not so performing and elegant. Which is the correct way to do this?

And If I would to find the results that have the values in the set with at max n errors? (for example, n=2 --> find all the records which have all the values in the set and all the records that have +2 (at max two values in addition) and -2 (at max two values in subtraction) values in set).

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` to make sure all different ID_A values are found:

```
select ID_B
from AB
where ID_A in (12, 15, 26)
group by ID_B
having count(distinct ID_A) = 3
```